# Hot reloading .js files in Weblogic with eclipse

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, weblogic, weblogic-10.x

I am to trying to enable hot reloading in Weblogic 10.3.3. I tried adding 
`<resource-reload-check-secs>1</resource-reload-check-secs>` 
to weblogic.xml (which supposed to be default value in debug mode), but it did not help. However, when I make changes to .jsp files there is no need for republishing.

Any suggestions on how to make it work (if this is even possible)?
Also, jrebel is not an option at the moment.

Comment: Have you checked if the files deploy? Normally, static content needs to be refreshed from browser, normally reloading with Ctrl-F5 or clearing cache...

Comment: I tried this. Caching is disabled via browser preferences, maybe it is related to the fact we are using IE6 (don't ask), but I really have no idea. Also, the server state indicator in the Eclipse Servers windows, is [Debugging, republish] when I save a change I made in a javascript file. However, it remains "synchronized" when a  jsp is changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it is related to whether the application is deployed in exploded or virtual mode. The workaround I found was to replace the file (A bit annoying but saves a redeploy).

Navigate to

```
<YOUR ECLIPSE WORKSPACE>\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources\.projects\<PROJECT NAME>\beadep\
```

There you will have your application files and you can simply replace the changed file.